Trying to edit a colorscale conditional format rule
Using script lab, I am trying to edit an existing colorscale conditional format rule.
Here's the Excel file in question: https://1drv.ms/x/s!AslIeJys_KO0hLUtAgeMDZd84wsDAw?e=cbXJq4
Here is the Script lab code:
https://1drv.ms/t/s!AslIeJys_KO0hLUuLBfDtr_vWE-z2w?e=bV0oVE
$("#run").on("click", () => tryCatch(run));

async function run() {
await Excel.run(async (context) => {
const sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();




let cfRules = sheet.getRange("D6").conditionalFormats;
let cf = cfRules.getItemAt(0);
let colScaleObject = cf.colorScaleOrNullObject;
colScaleObject.load("criteria");
await context.sync();
console.log(colScaleObject.criteria);
let criteria = {
  minimum: {
    formula: colScaleObject.criteria.minimum.formula,
    type: colScaleObject.criteria.minimum.type,
    color: colScaleObject.criteria.minimum.color,
  },
  midpoint: {
    formula: colScaleObject.criteria.midpoint.formula,
    type: colScaleObject.criteria.midpoint.type,
    color: colScaleObject.criteria.midpoint.color,
  },
  maximum: {
    formula: "CFSetting456_2",
    type: colScaleObject.criteria.maximum.type,
    color: colScaleObject.criteria.maximum.color,
  },
};
colScaleObject.criteria = criteria;

await context.sync();

});
}

/** Default helper for invoking an action and handling errors. */
async function tryCatch(callback) {
try {
  await callback();
} catch (error) {
  // Note: In a production add-in, you'd want to notify the user through your add-in's UI.
  console.error(error);
}
}

The problem is, the code appears to run just fine, but the CF rule stops working! I can make the CF rule work again by opening the CF rule, making a bogus edit and OK-ing.
What is wrong with my code?
